# Put http.NewServeMux into http.NewServeMux

Tags: http, go

This is my code. I want to put mux1 as sub router into mux.Handle. Next, I run the code. I can visit path /index but I cannot visit path /index/sub1.
I don't know why I can visit /index but I cannot visit /index/sub1?

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux1 := http.NewServeMux()
    mux1.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "sub index")
    })
    mux1.HandleFunc("/sub1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "sub 1")
    })

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/index", mux1)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
}
```

Comment: What in `go doc net/http.ServeMux` makes you think that this is doable? (It is not). Use ServMux as designed or use some other router.

Comment: The http.NewServeMux is a type of Handler, so I think it can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example doesn't work, because you used the `/index` path to register the "outer" handler, which is a single path (because it does not end with a slash `/`) and not a rooted subtree (that is, all paths starting with `/index/`). This is documented at [`http.ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux):

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.

And also because the "subrouter" will not see a path like `"/"` or `"/sub1"` which you used to register handlers, but the **full** path, that is: `"/index/"` and `"/index/sub1"`.

So what the main router should do is "strip" the `"/index"` prefix which is the path it was registered to (without the trailing slash). Fortunately, the standard lib has a ready-solution for this: [`http.StripPrefix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix).

So the working solution:

```
mux1 := http.NewServeMux()
mux1.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "sub index")
})
mux1.HandleFunc("/sub1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "sub 1")
})

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/index/", http.StripPrefix("/index", mux1))

http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
```

Testing it:

- URL: `http://localhost:8000/index/`
  Response: `sub index`
- URL: `http://localhost:8000/index/sub1`
  Response: `sub 1`